# How to specify target OS in V4 printer driver INF file

Tags: printing, driver, wdk

For V3 printer drivers you could specify architecture as well as target OS in an INF file.  Does V4 driver INF file supports this also?  If yes, is target OS specified the same way as in V3 drivers?  If not, can one assume that every V4 driver will run on Server 2012 and up?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, note that Target OS means only windows different versions. Any other operating systems are not supported by MS V4 Printer Driver Model.
Inside an .INF file there is "Signature" entry under [Version] section (Normally at the very top of the file) that indicates the operating systems for which this INF file is valid. For more information see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/inf-version-section).

An .INF file must supply OS-specific installation information by appending system-defined extensions to its driver installation sections (like [DriverInstall], [DriverFiles], [SourceDiskName], etc sections) whether the signature-name is "$Windows NT$" or "$Chicago$". For more information about creating .INF files for multiple platforms and operating systems see [here](http://Creating%20INF%20Files%20for%20Multiple%20Platforms%20and%20Operating%20Systems).